# How to save a variable and read it on the next run

Tags: python, datetime

How to compare today's date with the date from the last run (could be today's or yesterday's date)?

```
curr_date = date.today()
run_date = # depends on last run
```

this `run_date` variable should contain previous day's date. After the script has run the run date should be updated

```
run_date = curr_date
```

The variable `curr_date` will be updated everyday when the program is run using job to execute it every 24 hours.

What I want to do is when the first time program is executed both `curr_date` and `run_date` should contain same values, which is today's date. But when next time `curr_date` and `run_date` are compared, the date of the last run should be assigned to `run_date` and todays date to `curr_date`.

`wait` will not work because I don't want to pause my program just for some condition.

this is the condition I want to run:

```
if curr_date > run_date:
    batch_id = batch_id + 1
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How are those variables updated every day? Is it your job to update them? You'd compare these two dates the same way you'd compare any two dates. What are you trying to accomplish here? Please [edit] your question to contain enough details so that it can be answered. See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't have a background task that just sleeps for 24hrs and then wakes up again, but indeed you have a script execution per day, maybe scheduled by a `cronjob`.

To transport data/variables from one execution to the next, you need to "save" the data from the last run and reload it whenever the script is executed.
I suggest a solution using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

I also assume that you only need to save `last_run` date and can get todays date with `date.today()`.

---

Here is an example script that reads the `datetime` object, corresponding to the `last_run`, from a `pickle` file. Whenever you execute the script a check is performed if the pickle store exists. If not it is assumed that this is the first run and the last run date is set as todays date.

```
import os
import pickle
from datetime import date


STORE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'last_run.pickle')

today = date.today()
print("Today is", today)

# Load the stored date from last run:
if os.path.isfile(STORE):
    print('Read last_run from:', STORE)
    with open(STORE, 'rb') as store:
        last_run = pickle.load(store)
else:
    print('No STORE detected. Assuming this is the first run...')
    last_run = today

print("Last run was", last_run)
if last_run < today:
    # Do what needs to be done
    pass

# store todays run date for the next run:
with open(STORE, 'wb') as store:
    pickle.dump(today, store)

print('Saved last_run to:', STORE)
```

---

For the very first run we get

```
Today is 2022-12-16
No STORE detected. Assuming this is the first run...
Last run was 2022-12-16
Saved last_run to: last_run.pickle
```

If a pickle file exists the output would read like

```
Today is 2022-12-16
Read last_run from: last_run.pickle
Last run was 2022-12-15
Saved last_run to: last_run.pickle
```

---

Please note that this is a very basc example that does not cover everything you might want to think of. E.g. error handling: What happens if an error is raised. Here there would be no saving of the `last_run` data. That could be desired or not, depending on your requirements.